# pythonでデータが連続値かどうかを識別する

Tags: python

1行ごとにエポックタイムが昇順に記載されているテキストファイルがあり、各行のエポックタイムが1分づつのように等間隔で増加しているかどうかを確認したいのですが、テキストファイルのデータが連続値かどうかを識別するpythonのライブラリはないでしょうか?

Comment: １行ずつ回して、１行前の値を一時変数に保存しておいて、比較すればいいのでは。

Answer (score 2):

strptime()で日時をあらわす文字列から、datetimeに変換できます。例えば、以下のような感じで。

```
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.strptime('2014/01/01 00:01:02', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

strptimeの第一引数('2014/01/01 00:01:02'の部分)を、テキストファイルの1行から日時を抜き出したものに変え、第二引数('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'の部分)をテキストファイルで用いられている日時表記の形式に変えてください

上下の行で、それぞれから取り出したdatetimeの差を求めて、どの行の間でも差が同じなら等間隔という事になります。

Answer (score 0):

エポックタイムが`1970年1月1日午前0時0分0秒から形式的な経過秒数`、いわゆる[UNIX Time](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX%E6%99%82%E9%96%93)を指していると仮定します。これは精度が秒なので、各行毎に数字が`60`ずつ増加しているか確認すれば良い、ということになります。

私の知る限りでは、少なくともそのようなライブラリは存在しません。

扱うテキストファイルのフォーマットが不明ですが、仮に1カラムのみのファイルとすると、下記コードで目的が達成できそうです。

t.py:

```
def validate(cur, prev):
  if prev is None: return None # default
  return cur == (prev + 60)

with open('t.csv', 'r') as f:
  prev = None
  for n, l in enumerate(f, 1):
    epoch = int(l, 10)
    is_valid = validate(epoch, prev)
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(n, epoch, is_valid))
    prev = epoch
```

t.csv:

```
1527122450
1527122510
1527122550
```

execute and result:

`python t.py`

> 1       1527122450      None
>   2       1527122510      True
>   3       1527122550      False